# Create a new column such that, each row contains the row number of nearest row-record by euclidean distance

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100, 40).reshape(10, -1), columns=list('pqrs'), index=list('abcdefghij'))

# Solution
import numpy as np

nearest_rows = []
nearest_distance = []


for i, row in df.iterrows():
    curr = row
    rest = df.drop(i)
    e_dists = {} 
    for j, contestant in rest.iterrows():
        
        e_dists.update({j: round(np.linalg.norm(curr.values - contestant.values))})
   
    nearest_rows.append(max(e_dists, key=e_dists.get))
    nearest_distance.append(max(e_dists.values()))

df['nearest_row'] = nearest_rows
df['dist'] = nearest_distance
```

I need to Create a new column such that, each row contains the row number of nearest row-record by euclidean distance. but the last part keeps errorring I dont know what to do. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Why do you want a minimum distance?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Could you post the full error message and traceback?